# Real Screen Resolution not fake

Tags: css, browser, responsive-design

I have been working on creating a responsive website using twitter bootstrap. In order to see how my website worked on different resolutions, I used t[his google chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal?hl=en).

I sourced this article which told me the resolution of the Nexus 7 is 1200 x 800. [This](http://www.google.com/nexus/4/specs/) told me the resolution of my Nexus 4 is 1280 x 768.

However, when I set these resolutions on the plugin, the website looks differently on the browser than it does on the devices. The resolution seems higher on my macbook pro then on my Nexus 7, as things fit better on the laptop when using a browser size of 1200 x 800.

The mobile devices seem to have smaller displays that they report. It seems the Nexus 4 display is only (approx.) 480px wide sometimes.

**Why is that?**

I have a hunch that it has to do with ppi. But if that's the case, how do I test responsive designs on my laptop with the proper correspondance? Is there a formula I can use to figure out what browser window size to test it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure are using a viewport tag, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`. The key being the `width=device-width` part. See [this MDN article on the how this works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score 0):

Nexus4 has a resolution of 768*1280 px and a pixel-ration of 2.
Which means, you have 768*1280 real pixels (physical) and only
768/2, 1280/2 => 384*640 px software resolution ie in-app resolution ie browser resolution.
Why? Coz of the "trending" ppi madness and coz of some mystical ppl seeing "pixels" (never seen those pixels even on desire bravo). ppl are sick, so manufacturers made this trick.